# tables in lyx that flow with the text

Tags: tables, floats, lyx

I have been using `float:table` as my default for tables. I insert a `float:table`, then in that float I insert a child document (as input) that contains all my latex code for the table. This works fine but puts each table on its own page. I would like tables to flow with the text. That is have tables take up as much or little space as it needs and for text to continue. I currently use the `endfloat` package to put all my tables at the end of the document so one table per page is fine but I would like to convert it now to be part of the text. Here is an example of a document that does this:

https://www.princeton.edu/~markus/research/papers/carry_trades_currency_crashes_old.pdf

Comment: right-click on `float:Table` and go to `Settings`. Unclick "Use default placement" and click "Here definitely". If you have other problems, please post a LyX minimal example: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right-click on the float:Table and go to "Settings". Unclick "Use default placement" and click "Here definitely".